# What is the rigth way to call a function in one activity from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

What is the right way to call a function in an `activity` from another `activity`.
I used to do it by creating  a `static object` of the first `activity` and calling it from the second `activity`. But this method is method is said to cause memory leaks. 
So what is the right method to do it?

Comment: use a singleton. define the method in singleton class

Comment: what will that method do for example?

Comment: The fucncton can be for calling a web servise or removing an item from a arraylist. I need to do this in many activitys. Right now I store the context of the activit in a class as static object.

Answer (score 0):

The method you described causes memory leaks only if you store somewhere Context/Activity.

There are classes in android sdk which uses the same approach(for example Toast)

Comment: i am using a class to store the static objects. How to do it without storing the context?

Comment: which objects do you store?

Comment: I store a context of the first activity in the class and use this context in the second activity to call the function in the first activty.